# Update column of another table from another table model rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table called Application and another table called Application_Case_Status

in my code, I create the applications and i want to update the application_case_status table column "application-source".

Upon creating an application, one of the column is :case_code ="OF-123" or "ON-123"

In my Application_case_Status table, i hv a column `:loan_application_id and :application_source`

My code in application.rb

```
after_create :generate_source_id

def generate_source_id 

    application_object = Application.find(self.id)

    if application_object.case_code.include? "OF-" 
      update_attribute(:application_source, "Manual Upload")
    end
    if self.case_code.include? "ON-"
      update_attribute(:application_source, "Website")
    end
  end
```

I get error that it cant find column :application_source how can i get it to update this column which is Application_Case_Status table

Comment: Your `ApplicationCaseStatus` table probably has a lot of entities, how do you know which one you want to update? Is there a relationship between `Application` and `ApplicationCaseStatus`?

Comment: relationship yes application_id is reference in ApplicationCaseStatus

Comment: It would be helpful to have more info. Please post your table schema and the exact error, which will probably include "ActiveRecord:: ...

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, it seems that it tries to update column of table Application but Application table doesn't have column named "application_source".

You need to update table Application_case_Status

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You don't need `application_object = Application.find(self.id)` because `self` is the `application_object` already.

Furthermore, you have two `if` statements but it looks like they can't be both true at the same time so you should convert them to one `if...else`.

So, assuming:

```
class Application
  has_one :application_case_status
end

class ApplicationCaseStatus
  belongs_to :application
end
```

your method should look like this:

```
def generate_source_id
  # we are going to check "case_code" **once** and feed the "application_source" variable
  application_source = 
    if self.case_code.include? "OF-"
      "Manual Upload"
    else
      "Website"
    end
  # and then we are going to create the "ApplicationCaseStatus" entity
  ApplicationCaseStatus.create!(:application_id = self.id, :application_source, application_source)
end
```

Notice, as per @Tien Nguyen's remark, that we are **creating** an `ApplicationCaseStatus` entity because we have assumed it's not created already. If that's not the case, you should just update it (`self.application_case_status.update_attribute!(:application_source, application_source)`)

Let me know if something doesn't work quite as you want it or doesn't make sense.

Comment: i think it right to assume that at the moment after creating Application, there is no ApplicationCaseStatus. So i would suggest to create rather than update the entity

Comment: @TienNguyen That's a good assumption, I am going to edit my answer to include your remark.